# contentEditable javascript caret placement in div

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I have a `contentEditable` div.

Let's say the user clicks a button that inserts HTML into the editable area.

So, they click a button and the following is added to the `innerHTML` of the `contentEditable` div:

```
<div id="outside"><div id="inside"></div></div>
```

How do I automatically place the cursor (ie caret) IN the "inside" div?
Worse, how can this work in IE and FF?

Answer (score 7):

For IE:

```
var range= document.body.createTextRange();
range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById('inside'));

range.select();
```

For Mozilla:

```
var range= document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(document.getElementById('inside'));

var selection= window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
```

In theory the Mozilla version should also work in Webkit and Opera. In practice Webkit selects nothing and Opera selects the whole page. Sigh. This is still not well-supported territory.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i could understand from your question:

If it is contentEditable editable/typeable, you may try this:

```
  // you insert content with your code and after that
  document.getElementById('contentEditable_id_here').focus();
```

Comment: Yes, that sets the focus on the main contentEditable div, but I'm looking to put the cursor (or caret) in the <div id="inside"></div> tags so when the user starts typing, that's where there cursor is already.

Answer (score 0):

FYI focus() doesn't work for non-form elements with contentEditable enabled in Google Chrome (I just tried it on a `<li>` inside a list that is editable and nothing happened in Chrome 10.0.648.82 beta on Win XP Pro SP3).