# How can I move the caret between contenteditable list items (of varying indents) while maintaining caret x offset?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I have a list of items with varying indents like so:

- List item 1

  - List item 2

    - List item 3

I turn on `contentEditable` when the user clicks a list item. Now, when the user presses the `up` arrow key, I want to move the caret/word cursor from, say `List item 3` to `List item 2`, while *maintaining the caret's x position*.

To show this graphically,

`intial caret pos:`

- List item 2

  - Li **|** st item 3

`final caret pos after user presses up arrow. x offset remains same despite the difference in indent levels:`

- List ite **|** m 2

  - List item 3

The aim is to simulate the behavior of a multi-line text area where moving between lines using the arrow keys preserves the caret offset. You can also see this behavior while moving between list items in Google Tasks.

[After](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892866/contenteditable-javascript-caret-placement-in-div) [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233265/contenteditable-set-caret-at-the-end-of-the-text-cross-browser) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181700/set-cursor-position-on-contenteditable-div) [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816078/rangy-contenteditable-set-the-caret) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059254/current-x-y-coordinates-of-cursor-in-text-area-using-javascript) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082921/get-caret-xy-coordinates-in-text-area) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213376/how-to-find-cursor-position-in-a-contenteditable-div) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844649/javascript-contenteditable-getting-setting-caret-position), I managed to get half way to solving the problem before giving up.

Anyone aware of an elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

The general approach I'd suggest is:

- Intercept the `keydown` event and prevent the browser default when up or down arrows are pressed
- Here are some functions that allow you to get and set the position of the caret as character indices relative to a particular element. They're imperfect but would do the job in most circumstances: [replace innerHTML in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595956/replace-innerhtml-in-contenteditable-div/5596688#5596688) (also [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8pJ7/8/) does the same but removes the dependency on the Rangy library). Use these to get the the caret character index relative to one `<li>` and set the caret to the same position relative to the `<li>` above or below.